# since there's no countifs with OR

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to determine if either column H >1 and/or column I >1...basically a yes or no answer...but I don't want a value of 2 if both of them are...I'm having to put whatever formula will do this over in column M because all of the preceding columns are already the product of a query (you'll see that in cell A3)

[this is the sheet I'm in](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oXWwnLNc5YvpGGDw8G0GIQ7qx_c0_Q2QVX4FjCkM57I/edit#gid=511363971)

Comment: your sheet is View Only, so solutions can't be tested or demo'd

Comment: argh sorry permissions changed to edit @MattKing

Comment: You said you wanted to "determine", but you didn't say what your real goal output is in column M?

Comment: I love what you did with the Y or N, that's perfect. Thanks @MattKing

Comment: Ok good! As long as you understand why/ how it works!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you just add them to check if the sum is greater than 1?

```
=N(H3+I3>1)
```

N() turns true falses into 1s and 0s